# Is there any way to represent many to many relationship without using junction tables?

Tags: sql, erd

And in addition to that, when you are drawing out ERD diagrams should you include the "junction" tables as entities, even though they are not explicitly mentioned in the spec, but you can clearly see that it is many to many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entities that you include in an ERD really depend upon the intended audience.  If you plan on presenting an ERD to software engineers or database administrators then omitting the associative tables would just be confusing.  If you are trying to give a high level system overview, then I would advise leaving out everything except the entities that are directly relevant to system operation.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, junction table aka "cross-walk" tables are important to show data flow.

I think leaving these cross-walk tables out of the ERD, may make viewing the logical flow of the data difficult to comprehend for someone new to the ERD. As your data model becomes more complex, it makes it increasingly difficult to comprehend if you do not show them.

Comment: So would it be correct to assume that they are not required, but simply can make your (or other peoples) life easier?

Comment: Not required, but critical for understand-ability.